# Hide folders using htaccess file

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I have a website. and i am uploading successfully.
I have some folders on that website like /css, /scripts, /images

My website name is looking like this www.mydomain.com

when i am going to type url the webpage(index.html) is looking good. but i am going to type www.mydomain.com/css or  www.mydomain.com/scripts or www.mydomain.com/images the whole data is displayed. I want to hide sub folders like /css, /scripts, /images. It is only possible using .htaccess. Now my question is how to hide sub folders in website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Accept the question for others to know.